# How do I move local, unpushed, commits from a corrupt git repository to another repository?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Normally I can move pushed commits to another repository using `cherry-pick`: I `fetch` the related branch from 'another' repository to my new repo and `cherry-pick` with commit's ID.

I want to do the same thing for local--unpushed--commits in a corrupt repository (something went wrong and I cannot push my changes, but I need to move them to another repo).

Is there any way to `cherry-pick` commits from the corrupt repo to another repo?

PS: Both repositories exist on the same machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible method.

```
cd repo1_path
git format-patch -1 <commit> --stdout > /tmp/xxx.patch
cd repo2_path
git checkout <branch>
git am /tmp/xxx.patch
```

Comment: does that <commit> stand for SHA?

Comment: @likeachamp yes, the one you want to move. It could be a branch, a tag, or sha1 that represents the commit.

Comment: Amazing! As my old repo is corrupted, this one is the perfect solution for me.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify date range for commits instead of picking one by one?

Comment: @likeachamp yes, there are some ways to specify revision range. `-1 <commit>` could be `-n commit` where `n` is a positive number. `<commit1>..<commit2` is also ok. For example `A-B-C-D-E`, `-4 E` means `BCDE`. So does `A..E` or `B^..E`. But I'm afraid *date* range is not supported by `git format-patch`. It needs some extra efforts to filter or remove the unwanted patches.

Answer (score 4):

Do you just need to push commits from one local repo to another local repo?

```
git remote add local /path/to/repo.git
git push local master
```

Comment: yes but not all of them. spesific ones. I assume i can cherry-pick after first step

Comment: Yes after the first command you can treat the remote as another remote, because it really is no different.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that part

Answer (score 3):

Remotes aren't limited to another machine: If you have one repository at `/repo1` and another at `/repo2` you can copy commits from `repo1` to `repo2` by simply adding `repo1` as a remote to `repo2` using filesystem paths:

```
cd /repo2
git remote add repo1 /repo1
```

You can now `fetch`, `pull`, and `cherry-pick` commits from `repo1` to `repo2`.

Comment: is there anyway to cherry-pick without adding it? one file under .git/objects is corrupted so i cannot add as a remote or push my changes etc.

Comment: No, you can't do a `cherry-pick` if you can't add the repo as a remote: Your best bet is to try @ElpieKay's answer to export a patch (effectively a manual `cherry-pick`).