# Move unpushed, local branch commits to a new repository

Tags: git, version-control

I am creating a new version of a project that I have no rights. Unfortunately I started making my changes (more than 20 local commits) and realized my mistake when I wanted to push my changes.

For example I am working with `ProjectA` on branch `local` with the **unpushed, local** commits, can I transfer the entire `local` branch to a new `ProjectB` as `master`?

I know that I can just contact the developer of the original project to give me temporary rights to solve my problem. However I am curious if there is an existing way to do this with just Git commands.

I have already found:

- "[How do I create a new GitHub repo from a branch in an existing repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527999/how-do-i-create-a-new-github-repo-from-a-branch-in-an-existing-repo)" - requires pushed commits
- "[How do I move local, unpushed, commits from a corrupt git repository to another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538057/how-do-i-move-local-unpushed-commits-from-a-corrupt-git-repository-to-another)" - I need the history of my local branch, not just the patch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just alter the push target.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/ProjectB.git
```

Comment: Thank you! It never crossed my mind that I can just modify the origin :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new empty repository (say, `projectB`). Then add a new remote (say, `projectb`) with the URL of `projectB` into your `projectA`.

```
 $ git remote add projectb <projectB-url>      # add a new remote called 'projectb' with the url of project 'projectB'
```

Now Push your `projectA` repo's `local` branch commits/changes to `projectbB` repo's `master` branch.

```
$ git checkout local         # make sure you are in 'local' branch
$ git push projectb master
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you still want to make contribute for the origin github repo. **So you can fork this repo and then push your local changes to the fork repo** by:

```
git remote add fork <URL for the fork repo> -f
git checkout local
git push fork master
```

Now the `master` branch of fork repo contains your local changes. You can create a pull request to merge your changes to original github repo.